# Is there any way to use Kinect SDK remotely with network?

Tags: kinect, azurekinect

The Azure Kinect sensor SDK requires Kinect to connect directly to pc via usb, but it's not appropriate to me. Is it posible to use something like raspberry pi to transfer kinect sensor data and process on a remote server? Do you have any suggestions for this?

*I found the Kinect sdk does not support ARM architecture(raspberry pi)，what other device can I use?*

Answer (score 1):

Processing the depth camera image requires GPU compute, so we don't currently support headless operation. There are some users that have successfully enabled headless operation on Linux, but it is not a straight forward path. See https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/810 for more info.